# warning 21 warning failed to move file

Tags: iis, joomla2.5

i am using web sites developed in Joomla and i have hosted in my IIS 7 local server (Win Server 2008) and the website is live, but when client login to my website and try to upload file, they get the error `warning 21 warning failed to move file`

I went to Site -> Global Configuration, There i found the path of my logs and tmp are `c:/xampp/htdoc/site/tmp` & `c:/xampp/htdoc/site/logs` respectively.

please help me whats wrong with my configuration.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the permission of folder where you want to store your file. Set the permission of that folder `777`. You need to set `777` permission to these folder:

1. tmp
2. logs
3. Folder , where you need to save your file.

Hope this will help you.